# Why this formula for 5 year trend?

Tags: trend, excel

I've opened a spreadsheet that has a 5-year trend formula that I don't understand.

The sample data for $2012$ to $2016$ are: $190, 175, 160, 165, 200$.

The formula in the spreadsheet is:

$trend = 0.1*(-2*190+-1*175+0*160+1*165+2*200)/average(190, 175, 160, 165, 200) = 0.6\%$.

My questions are:

- Is this formula standard practice?
- Why are the weights ${-2,-1,0,1,2}$ used?
- Why is the quantity multiplied by $0.1$?

Comment: I assume you can't ask the creator of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Note that the method in question outputs 9.5% for an exact 10% per annum growth. For smaller percentages, it seems to be a feasible approximation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The formula is the linear regression of the series (whatever the variable is), which I will call $y$, on time ($x$), giving units-of-$y$ per year. This is then divided by average $y$ and the result given as a percentage to get a percentage annual growth relative to the mean $y$ (the estimate of the middle-year value of $y$).

Note that the slope of a regression line is $$\hat{\beta}=\frac{\sum_i (y_i-\bar{y}) (x_i-\bar{x})}{\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})^2}\,.$$

Now for the $x$'s being five consecutive years $(x_i-\bar{x})$ will always be $-2,-1,0,1,2$ and $\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})^2=10$.

At the same time

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_i (y_i-\bar{y}) (x_i-\bar{x})&=&\sum_i y_i (x_i-\bar{x}) - \bar{y}\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})\\
&=&\sum_i y_i (x_i-\bar{x})\,,
\end{eqnarray}

but again the $x_i-\bar{x}$'s are just $-2, ..., 2$ so that's $-2 \, y_1 - 1 \, y_2 + 0 \, y_3 + 1 \, y_4 + 2 \, y_5$.
(Note that $\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})$ is always $0$, which is why the second term disappeared.)

Consequently the estimated yearly increase using a least squares straight line fit is $\hat{\beta}= (-2 \, y_1 - 1 \, y_2 + 0 \, y_3 + 1 \, y_4 + 2 \, y_5)/10$. This will be in units-of-$y$ per year.

Now to get this to be a yearly relative (or percentage) increase we need to divide by a $y$-value. The mean of the $y$'s, $\bar{y}$ (which is also the estimated middle value in the trend line) is what they've divided by. I don't know why that particular choice was made, rather than some other possible choice --  but for some things I guess this would be a reasonable thing to do.

I don't know if this is standard, but I bet you could find a formula like this (estimated annual linear increase divided by the mean) in some business stats books or a similar source.

Comment: The only step that is a bit harder to follow is that `y_bar * sum(x - x_bar) = 0` because `sum(x - x_bar) = 0`

Comment: So we use a regression for the *linear* growth and try to estimate an *exponential* growth with it? I suppose, it would be more adequate to make a linear regression of the $\ln y_i$ and then use $\exp \tilde\beta$

Comment: @icc97 a product of two things is zero only if at least one of the two terms in the product is zero. In this case it's easy to figure out which of the two must be 0 ($\bar{y}$ certainly isn't in the example, so that's a big clue which term to focus on), and then to see that it will always be so. I can edit a brief comment in though.

Comment: I was just trying to explain it for others, I wasn't initially sure why the $\bar{y}$ term drops out. Once seen it's obvious enough. Might also help slightly if you put the final equation of that line on a separate line

Comment: Yes, understood; I was simply explaining how people should be able to see it quickly